# Count correct answers from radio input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button, checked

I have to count the correct answers from 10 different questions.
The questions are formulated like so:

```
<input type='radio' name='question1'>answer wrong<br>
<input type='radio' name='question1' value='correct'>answer correct<br>
<input type='radio' name='question2'>answer wrong<br>
<input type='radio' name='question2' value='correct'>answer correct<br>
```

This script runs every time a question is answered:

```
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
if (input[i].value=="correct") {
    if (input[i].checked==true){
        correct++
    }
}
console.log(correct)
}
```

For some reason, after one question is answered correctly, the counter will keep adding 1 `var correct`
for every answer given after that, even if the answer is wrong or not checked at all. If there are 2 questions answered correctly, it will keep adding 2 for every answered question after that, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do this is to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the correctly checked answers:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][value=correct]:checked').length
```

- `input` we only want to look at **inputs**
- `[type=radio]` the input must be a **radio** button
- `[value=correct]` the radio must have a value of **correct**
- `:checked` the **correct** radio must be **checked**

Here is a working example:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let correct = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][value=correct]:checked').length
    console.log(correct)
  })
})
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='question1'>answer wrong<br>
<input type='radio' name='question1' value='correct'>answer correct<br>
<input type='radio' name='question2'>answer wrong<br>
<input type='radio' name='question2' value='correct'>answer correct<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is counting the correct answers at any one time, you are just adding all the correct answers to a variable that is never reset.

There are many ways to do this. You can reset the counter variable each time it checks all the answers, and at the end check how many are correct.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
if (input[i].value=="correct") {
    if (input[i].checked==true){
        correct++
    }
}
console.log(correct);
if(i==input.length)correct = 0;
}

if(correct == 10){console.log("player got 100%");}
```